# Symfony2 - Umlauts are displayed as a question mark

Tags: php, symfony, templates, encoding, twig

I got a problem somehow my text with umlauts is being displayed with question marks. As seen here:

[image: Here is the text with umlauts]

My template extends base.html.twig, which includes the meta tag for the charset (UTF-8) as seen here:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

As you can see the request is being sent with the correct charset:

[image: Request header]

I want to add that I don't fetch anything from the database it's just plain text in my template index.html.twig like here:

```
<div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        Erklären.....
</div>
```

I use my site on an IIS Websever. How do I fix my problem? I can't get any further.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: It may be that your files are not encoded in UTF-8. What IDE do you use ?

Comment: I use PHPStorm 9.0.1. You were right, the encoding wasn't set to UTF-8. Thank you very much! I thought that an IDE like PHPStorm would do that automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solution**

Thanks to Christophe Willemsen I could solve the problem. The problem was that my IDE PHPStorm didn't save the files with UTF-8 Encoding, which I thought would happen automatically.

Thank you Christophe!

Comment: Would be helpful if you shared how you edited this in PHPStorm, as I have the same issue, as does others from google... https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/file-encodings.html